# Way to use mongodb's find cursor's next/each functions as a promise after promisifying mongodb with Bluebird

Tags: node.js, mongodb, promise, bluebird, node-mongodb-native

- The node mongodb [docs](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/crud/#read-methods) specify to use next/each for large number of documents so as to not have everything loaded onto memory if we were to use toArray.
- So, i thought my sample code should work as is. But it just returns one document.
- What should be the correct way to deal with this problem?

This is my code sample :

```
var findAsync = function (collection,query) {
    return mongodb.MongoClient.connectAsync(mongodbServerString)
    .then(function (db) {
        return [db.collection(collection).find(query), db];
    });
};

findAsync("UserProfile",{})
.spread(function (cursor,db) {
    return [cursor.project({Email:true}),db];
})
.spread(function (cursor, db) {
    return cursor.eachAsync().then(function (doc) {
        console.log(doc);
    }).catch(function () {
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promises represent singular values. Promises are basically like function `return`s, since a function cannot return multiple values - it wouldn't make sense to convert `each` to a promise returning function.

What you can do is either convert it to an [Observable](https://github.com/zenparsing/es-observable) returning function and then use `.forEach` on that to get a promise back for the completion of the sequence or you can implement something similar manually:

```
function each(cursor, fn) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cursor.forEach((err, data) => {
           if(err) {
             cursor.close();
             return reject(err);
           }
           try { fn(data); } catch(e) { cursor.close(); reject(e); }
        }, err => { { // finished callback
           if(err) reject(err);
           else resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

Which would let you write:

```
each(cursor, doc => console.log(doc)).then(...).catch(...)
```

Also note that Mongo connections are persistent, you're supposed to connect once when the server starts and then keep the connection open for as long as the server is run.

Comment: Maybe wrap the `fn()` call in a `try catch`?

Comment: By the way, do you know if there is a way to stop a `forEach` in mongo early?

Comment: Nah, no idea. Don't think so.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - Thanks, I understood why iterating function in `cursor.eachAsync().then(iterator)`  will be called once. What i don't get is why is there data in the params of the function. when ideally there shouldn't be any. Bluebird does some sorcery while promisifying api.

I didn't get the part of converting to **Observable**.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum - The `forEach` function signature should be (iteratorCallback, endCallback) according to this [doc](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/api/Cursor.html#forEach). 

Also to help you out - There's a `cursor.close()` api to stop the cursor and there by `forEach` as well.

Comment: @kkaul you're welcome to post edits to my answer with the up to date signature - I'm a bluebird guy not a Mongo guy :) I'll add the parts I understand. As for observable - I mean an asynchronous primitive that's like a promise but for multiple values (like a functional style event emitter).